# How to sent one form values to 2 different sites in wordpress

Tags: email, forms

I am trying to post values in a form into 2 different urls. Is this possible?
Basically i want to have a form send the form optin values into aweber and send a email with the filled in values. I am on wordpress site but can have a php or html page if this is not possible using wordpress.

I currently have the aweber form to collect the info would like to send these values as email. Is this possible using any plugin or any hack

Thanks
Prady

Comment: ... aweber = ?? ...

Answer (score 3):

Short answer : YES.

Long answer: yes it possible but you will need to create your own form and form processing script to send the values by main and the use the [**Aweber api**](https://labs.aweber.com/docs/php-library-walkthrough) to register the new user in your list.

Just to get you started, you will need:

- An Aweber A free developer account. Don't have one yet? [Sign up here](https://labs.aweber.com/users/new)
- An app created in your labs account. (Have your keys handy)
- A copy of the [AWeber API PHP Library](https://github.com/aweber/AWeber-API-PHP-Library)